# Problema al enviar objetos por socket Java

Tags: java, socket, object

Tengo que crear dos aplicaciones cliente-servidor para enviar un objeto tipo persona del servidor al cliente. El problema es que al leerlo en el cliente de da error porque no ha encontrado la clase. Os pongo el codigo, la verdad que no doy con el error. La clase persona esta en los dos proyectos

Clase persona:

```
public class Persona implements Serializable {

private String nombre;
private int edad;


public Persona (String nombre, int edad){
    super();
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.edad=edad;
}
public String getNombre (){
    return nombre;
} 
public void setNombre(String n){
    this.nombre=n;
}
public int getEdad (){
    return edad;
}
public void setEdad (int a){
    this.edad=a;
}
```

clase Servidor:

```
public class Servidor {

static final int Puerto=1500;

public Servidor(){

    try {
        // Inicio el servidor en el puerto
        ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(Puerto);

        System.out.println("Escucho el puerto " + Puerto );

        Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept(); // Crea objeto            

        // Creo el flujo de salida             
        ObjectOutputStream flujo_salida= new ObjectOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());            

        // Creo el flujo de entrada            
        ObjectInputStream flujo_entrada= new ObjectInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("Cliente conectado"); 
        Persona persona=new Persona("Pablo",35);            

        flujo_salida.writeObject(persona);      

        // Se cierra la conexión
        skCliente.close();
        flujo_entrada.close();
        flujo_salida.close();
        System.out.println("Cliente desconectado");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

}
```

Clase Cliente:

```
public class Cliente {

static final String HOST = "localhost";
static final int Puerto=1500;

public Cliente( ) {

    Persona persona=null;        

    try{            
        // Me conecto al puerto
        Socket skCliente = new Socket( HOST , Puerto );              

        // Creo el flujo de salida             
        ObjectOutputStream flujo_salida= new ObjectOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());             

        // Creo el flujo de entrada            
        ObjectInputStream flujo_entrada= new ObjectInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream());         

        System.out.println("Conectado al servidor");

        persona=(cliente.Persona) flujo_entrada.readObject();      




        // Se cierra la conexión
        skCliente.close();
        flujo_entrada.close();
        flujo_salida.close();
        System.out.println("Cliente desconectado");            

    } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getMessage()+" "+e.toString() );                
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes añadir el error que mencionas?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info en como mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, añade el stacktrace (indicando en qué línea sale el error). Dicho esto, el programa parece correcto, lo único raro es que en el servidor creees un "flujo entrada" que no vas a usar pero eso no debería ser problema.

Answer (score 0):

el error que sale en la linea de codigo es class not fount.
Ya he encontrado el problema, despues de buscar en internet y demas el problema es que cuando se crea una clase, pone una cabecera al inicio y esta esta formada por el nombre del paquete punto nombre de la clase. En mi caso:

cliente.Persona

servidor.Persona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ahora cambiamos el nombre de estos paquetes y ponemos el mismo, problema solucionado. Otra opcion, aunque mas complicada, es crear nuestro propia clase ObjectOutputStream, heredando del original y redefiniendo el método writeStreamHeader() para que no haga nada:

protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
{
// No hacer nada.
}

Otra opcion es crear un paquete nuevo que se llame igual dentro de cada proyecto con la clase que se comparte

**También, se puede crear un jar que contenga la clase Persona y después agregar ese jar en el BUIL PATH tanto en el proyecto cliente como en el proyecto servidor**